# how to remove duplicate codes when bundling with esbuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, esbuild

I'm currently working on a backend project and I'm using nodejs and express.
I also use esbuild to bundle my code. here's my build script :

`"build": "esbuild src/server.ts --bundle --platform=node --outfile=dist/bundle.js --format=esm --packages=external",`

the problem is that in the bundle file i see things like :

```
import express3 from "express";
import express from "express";
import express2 from "express";
```

this is really strange to me because I expected to see only one express import in the whole bundle file but it turns out there's one for each usage in different files.
for example in my server.ts:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
```

or in my routers :

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
```

is there a problem with the build script or it's esbuild normal behavior ? because I think removing duplicate codes is one of the main thing a module bundler is supposed to do.

Comment: Why do you need to bundle backend code? If you want support for TS in node, you can simply use something like `tsx`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx

Comment: "*I think removing duplicate codes is one of the main thing a module bundler is supposed to do*" - no. The main purpose of a bundler is to put multiple modules in a single file, while preserving its behaviour. You might be thinking of a minifier.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your answer. by adding --minify to the build script , esbuild will minify the code as well but in the minified version the same problem exists.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica thanks for your answer and also for the package you introduced.
but this is not what I wanted.

Comment: @MRT I guess then it's just an optimisation opportunity that they have missed (or just not implemented yet). I'm sure they'd welcome a PR, I can't see any reason not to do this.